# Haskell - efficient equivalent for hash-based dictionary

Tags: haskell, dictionary, hashmap

I would like to construct a couple of "dictionaries" in Haskell as part of a project I am working on. I was wondering what would be some efficient data structures for doing so. A very naive approach would be to use a list of tuples, but I suspect that this would be quite inefficient.

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

P.S. I am creating this dictionaries by reading a corpus of raw text as the keys and some scores about the words as values.

Comment: How is efficiency measured here? Which operations and what expected/required bounds?

Comment: Check out [`containers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) (not hashed based) and [`unordered-containers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers) (hash based).

Comment: @duplode, I think it is, thanks for pointing that out!